# Get word list on Tess-Two

Tags: android, tesseract

I'm developing an app that utilizes OCR on Android. The tess-two sample is working pretty good and I can get the full OCR text but I want to know how I can get the individual words inside the boxes that Tesseract actually outputs. I can use getWords().getBoxRects() to get a list of the bounding boxes and it seems that the getWords() function does what I want but it returns a Pixa object and I'm not sure how a word list (of whatever words are contained inside the boxes) will be obtained from that.

The output I am looking for is a map with the following key-value:

Word : Bounding box

Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the hOCR output to obtain the words and their coordinates. See [Export HOCR output for tesseract OCR in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248288/export-hocr-output-for-tesseract-ocr-in-android).

Or use `ResultIterator` API, if `tess-two` supports it.