# Export HOCR output for tesseract OCR in android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I tried to use [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two), a fork of Tesseract Tools for Android. I want to turn on `hocr` output in tesseract, from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=377), I tried to set variable `tessedit_create_hocr` as true, but I can't see hocr in output. Here is my try:

```
  baseApi.init(FileUtil.getAppFolder(), "eng", TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
  baseApi.setVariable("tessedit_create_hocr", "1")
  baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
  String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

Somebody told the `hocr` output should be in config folder or in folder contain image, but I don't see anything. Any I don't know how to config the file name and location of hocr output.

Another thing: is there any way to apply config file into Tesseract Tools for Android? I put the config files into **tessdata/config folder**, but there is nothing happen. How to tell `tesseract` should read these config files? Seem they don't have enough documents for android.

**Update**: Thanks to `@nguyenq`, now I can get `HOCR` data. Here is my try:

```
  jstring Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeGetHOCRText(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                        jobject thiz,    jint page) {

 native_data_t *nat = get_native_data(env, thiz);

 char *text = nat->api.GetHOCRText(page);

 jstring result = env->NewStringUTF(text);

 free(text);

 return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `tess-two` does not implement all the `TessBaseAPI` as it does not include support for the native `GetHOCRText` method. You may have to extend the wrapper yourself to access the functions you need.

The config files are meant for command-line execution. Alternatively, you can set the necessary variables through the exposed API method `setVariable`.

Comment: I think that tess-two now supports GetHOCRText -- in particular, public String getHOCRText(int page) is defined on line 729 of TessBaseAPI.java.