# How to get each word and bounding box of recognized text in tess-two android

Tags: android, tesseract

I am using ResultIterator to get each word from an image but mine gives error when calling `iterator.begin()`. I don't know why.

Here is my current code,

```
//Global
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        final SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        //get camera params for ocr
        Camera.Parameters cameraParams = _camera.getParameters();
        int width = surfaceView.getWidth();
        int height = surfaceView.getHeight();
        PixelFormat pixFormat = new PixelFormat();
        PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(cameraParams.getPreviewFormat(), pixFormat);
        int bpp = pixFormat.bytesPerPixel;
        int bpl = bpp * width;

        //ocr
        ocr.setImage(data, width, height, bpp, bpl);
        ocr.setRectangle(0, 50, width, height - 50);

        // Iterate through the results.
        final ResultIterator iterator = ocr.getResultIterator();
        iterator.begin(); //crashes my app
        do {
            words.add(iterator.getUTF8Text(PageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD));
        } while (iterator.next(PageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD));
    }
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Tesseract's [`APIExample`](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample), you would need to call the `Recognize` method before you can get the iterator. You may need to implement this method for `tess-two`.

Another venue is through the `hOCR` ouput. See [Export HOCR output for tesseract OCR in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248288/export-hocr-output-for-tesseract-ocr-in-android).

Comment: Fortunately I have found an easier solution. I have to put `ocr.getUTF8Text()` first before calling the `ocr.getResultIterator()` and it worked.

Comment: That works too as `GetUTF8Text` calls `Recognize` behind the scene.